# "Fatal error: Class 'mod_virtuemart_product' not found

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I tried to install my module for live searching inside of mod_virtuemart_product module. I changed mod_virtuemart_product.xml in this way:

Old code

```
<install type="module" version="1.5.0">
    <name>mod_virtuemart_product</name>
    <creationDate>March 17 2013</creationDate>
    <author>The VirtueMart Development Team</author>
    <authorUrl>http://www.virtuemart.net</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2004-2012 Virtuemart Team. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
    <version>2.0.20b</version>
    <description>MOD_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DESC</description>
    <files>
    <filename module="mod_virtuemart_product">mod_virtuemart_product.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/default2.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/default3.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <params addpath="/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/elements">
    <param  name="layout" type="filelist" label="MOD_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_LAYOUT"
                description="MOD_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_LAYOUT_DESC"
                directory="/modules/mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl"
                default="default" hide_default="1" hide_none="1"
                stripext="1" filter="\.php$" exclude="^_" />
.
.
.
```

New code

```
<extension type="module" version="2.5" method="upgrade">
    <name>mod_virtuemart_product</name>
    <creationDate>March 17 2013</creationDate>
    <author>The VirtueMart Development Team</author>
    <authorUrl>http://www.virtuemart.net</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright (C) 2004-2012 Virtuemart Team. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
    <version>2.0.20b</version>
    <description>MOD_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DESC</description>
    <files>
    <filename module="mod_virtuemart_product">mod_virtuemart_product.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/default.php</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/index.html</filename>
    <filename>tmpl/quicksearch.php</filename>

    </files>
    <params addpath="/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/elements">
.
.
.
```

And I created in mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl folder new php files and javascript files in this way:

And I created in mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl folder new php files and javascript files in this way:

```
mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/quicksearch.php
mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/default.php - used by virtuemart (I just add to this code 
my search input code)
mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/head.php
mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/config.php
mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/js/javascript.js
mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/css/css.css
```

Everything is connected. My code is functional, but when I want to add this code to my quicksearch.php file: echo mod_virtuemart_product::addtocart ($product);

It writes me this error:

"Fatal error: Class 'mod_virtuemart_product' not found in /www/t/r/u46223/public_html/modules/mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl/quicksearch.php on line 34"

Could you please advice me, what is wrong?

Thank you.

---

Here is mod_virtuemart_product.php file. And I want to add this functions "mod_virtuemart_product::addtocart ($product)" to my file quicksearch.php, which I have in modules/mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl folder. Thanks.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Direct Access to '.basename(__FILE__).' is not allowed.' );
/*
* featured/Latest/Topten/Random Products Module
*
* @version $Id: mod_virtuemart_product.php 2789 2011-02-28 12:41:01Z oscar $
* @package VirtueMart
* @subpackage modules
*
*   @copyright (C) 2010 - Patrick Kohl
*
* @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
* VirtueMart is Free Software.
* VirtueMart comes with absolute no warranty.
*
* www.virtuemart.net
*/


if (!class_exists( 'VmConfig' )) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'config.php');

VmConfig::loadConfig();
VmConfig::loadJLang('mod_virtuemart_product', true);

// Setting
$max_items =        $params->get( 'max_items', 2 ); //maximum number of items to display
$layout = $params->get('layout','default');
$category_id =      $params->get( 'virtuemart_category_id', null ); // Display products from this category only
$filter_category =  (bool)$params->get( 'filter_category', 0 ); // Filter the category
$display_style =    $params->get( 'display_style', "div" ); // Display Style
$products_per_row = $params->get( 'products_per_row', 4 ); // Display X products per Row
$show_price =       (bool)$params->get( 'show_price', 1 ); // Display the Product Price?
$show_addtocart =   (bool)$params->get( 'show_addtocart', 1 ); // Display the "Add-to-Cart" Link?
$headerText =       $params->get( 'headerText', '' ); // Display a Header Text
$footerText =       $params->get( 'footerText', ''); // Display a footerText
$Product_group =    $params->get( 'product_group', 'featured'); // Display a footerText

$mainframe = Jfactory::getApplication();
$virtuemart_currency_id = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest( "virtuemart_currency_id", 'virtuemart_currency_id',JRequest::getInt('virtuemart_currency_id',0) );


$key = 'products'.$category_id.'.'.$max_items.'.'.$filter_category.'.'.$display_style.'.'.$products_per_row.'.'.$show_price.'.'.$show_addtocart.'.'.$Product_group.'.'.$virtuemart_currency_id;

$cache  = JFactory::getCache('mod_virtuemart_product', 'output');
if (!($output = $cache->get($key))) {
    ob_start();
    // Try to load the data from cache.


    /* Load  VM fonction */
    if (!class_exists( 'mod_virtuemart_product' )) require('helper.php');

    $vendorId = JRequest::getInt('vendorid', 1);

    if ($filter_category ) $filter_category = TRUE;

    $productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');

    $products = $productModel->getProductListing($Product_group, $max_items, $show_price, true, false,$filter_category, $category_id);
    $productModel->addImages($products);

    $totalProd =        count( $products);
    if(empty($products)) return false;
    $currency = CurrencyDisplay::getInstance( );

    if ($show_addtocart) {
        vmJsApi::jPrice();
        vmJsApi::cssSite();
    }
    /* Load tmpl default */
require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_virtuemart_product',$layout));
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    $cache->store($output, $key);
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try using Joomla 1.6+ manifest standards, so rather than using `<params>`, it should be structured like so:</strike>

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/elements">

            <field name="layout" type="filelist" label="MOD_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_LAYOUT"
            description="MOD_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_LAYOUT_DESC"
            directory="/modules/mod_virtuemart_product/tmpl"
            default="default" hide_default="1" hide_none="1"
            stripext="1" filter="\.php$" exclude="^_" />

            //more fields go here

        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Try including the helper.php file like so as it might not be included properly:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );
```

**Update:**

Wow! The **quicksearch.php** is completely wrong!

1. You're trying to manually include the **configuration.php**, which is wrong and can also pose security threats.
2. You're getting data from the database using **mysql_*** which does *not* only use Joomla 2.5 coding standards, but is deprecated and poses security threats.
3. You're using `$_POST` when again, this is not using Joomla 2.5 coding standards.

I hope you're not planning on putting this module on the Joomla Extensions Directory as you're on the road to getting your and other peoples sites hacked.

Please have a massive read through the [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I hav esome problems with PC, so I could not finish my question. So I finished it now. Could you please advice me with another part of it.

Comment: Ok it's not to do with your XML file, however my changes above still should be made. Please show all the code you have in `mod_virtuemart_product.php`.

Comment: Dear Lodder, I added it yet.

Comment: I have made a small change to my answer but I don't think it will resolve the issue. It's hard to tell without looking at all the files. Would you be able to upload the files for me to look at or send them to me via e-mail? All of them though.

Comment: No, this is my personnal module and I do not know about this things. I will study it. But could you please advice me, why there is fatal error occured? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to include helper.php in you're quicksearch.php. It only needs to be includes in mod_virtuemart_product.php

Comment: This page is just in test mode, so I will change this things as soon as possible. And I changed also link for mod_virtuemart_product folder. http://leteckaposta.cz/885810446

Comment: I tried even this way, but it wrote error as before:                                                           "Fatal error: Class 'mod_virtuemart_product' not found in... quicksearch.php"

Comment: The only problem is, is that I can't test anything as I'm getting errors because of the way you're connecting to the database. I'm no doing to do all the work for you and clean every bit of code just to find the problem. As I said before, read the Joomla documentation. Connect to the database properly and get the data. Then I will be more than happy to look at your code

Comment: Ok, I will try to clean it and then I will write here again. Thanks for advice.